# How to trap foreground and background events in a Javascript Win8 Metro App

Tags: javascript, windows-8, dom-events, microsoft-metro

Win8 Metro provides callback for when the process enters the activated and suspended states but what about when the app comes into the foreground or goes into the background? The process isn't necessarily suspended as soon as the app goes into the background and similarly it may come into the foreground while being still activated from the previous launch.

Are there any events in Javascript that can be used to execute code on foregrounding or backgrounding the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the application is placed into the background, but not suspended (yet), you can use the "visibilitychanged" event, and "hidden" property on the document object:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh773167(v=vs.85).aspx

These are fired the moment your app is no longer visible (e.g. the user hits the start button, or swipes to another application.

If your app is then suspended, you will *also* get the appropriate suspend events then.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, as soon as a metro app completely looses focus (goes completely off screen) it is given 15 seconds (I think) by the OS to run its OnSuspend code, before being stopped and suspended. This happens every time the whole app loses complete focus and the reverse happens when it gets focus again (the user switches back to it).

The code that you would to run in these foreground and background events should be put in the Suspension and Reactivation event handlers

Answer (score 0):

In Metro-style apps, the application will suspend when the user switches away from it and resume when the user switches back to it.  Metro-style apps run full-screen and immersive, so "suspend" is equivalent to what you are thinking of as "going into the background" and resuming is equivalent to coming into the foreground.

Once the suspend event is fired (when a user swipes away from your app), your app has 5 seconds to store off state.  In the suspend mode, your main thread of execution is suspended but the app is still held in memory.  The user may come back to your app shortly, and then the thread is resumed and that state that you stored is never used.  But, at some point, Windows may have too much in memory and need to terminate a process.  If your app is terminated, then you can use the state that you stored to restore your app to the way it was when it was terminated on the next time that it is run.

Check out these resources for more info:
* The different Application Execution states: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.activation.applicationexecutionstate.aspx
* Guidelines around this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465088.aspx